# Spring Data Neo4j close DB connection

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using the GraphRepository of the spring-data-neo4j(3.3.0.RELEASE) to do DB operations on Neo4J DB. And using the below configurations to establish the connect to the Neo4J DB.

```
<neo4j:config base-package="com.em.alert.model" graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="${alert.neo4j.url}" index="0"/>
</bean>
```

But when I finishes all the operations along with closing the Spring ApplicationContext, the DB connection with Neo4J DB is not getting closed.

Can anyone help me to figure out the way to close the DB connection to the Neo4J DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

add `destroy-method="shutdown"` to your bean

```
<neo4j:config base-package="com.em.alert.model" graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg value="${alert.neo4j.url}" index="0"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: it will not shutdown neo4j server

Comment: Actually I was doing all DB operation in to the treads using ExecutorService. But I forgot to shutdown the treads. So due to that the connections were not getting closed.
Thanks for your king support.